# Synthetic Divison with Polynomials!

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ok so the question is : Is $x+1$ a factor of $p(x)=x^3+3x^2+x-1$ ? If so, how do you find the other factors. I solved it synthetically and found out there is no remainder, so $x+1$ is indeed a factor of it. Im just stuck on how do you find other factors?

Comment: You only find other factors by finding where $p(x)=0$ which is not related to any division.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to check if $x-a$ is a factor is to check if $p(a)=0$, but your method works as well.

---

Doing synthetic division should show the coefficients of the polynomial $p(x)/(x+1)$.

\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 3 & 1 & -1\\
0 & -1 & -2 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 2 &-1 & 0
\end{array}
Looking at the third row shows that
$p(x) = (x+1)(x^2+2x-1)$. You can factor the quadratic using the quadratic formula or by completing the square.

Comment: ok so I factored it out and got x= -1plusminus the square root of 2. so does that mean theres no other factors or is that a factor? im confused

Comment: @ShelbyApplegate That means $x^2+2x-1 = (x-(-1 + \sqrt{2}))(x-(-1-\sqrt{2}))$.